# Opengl - Unbinding framebuffer clears attached textures

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, fbo, render-to-texture

I am having some trouble rendering to textures for later use. Currently, I am generating a framebuffer object, creating two textures (one RGB and one DEPTH_COMPONENT), attaching the two textures, checking the status which is okay, and then drawing while the framebuffer is bound. Inside of gDEBugger I can see that everything is being drawn to the textures just fine.

However, when I try to bind back to default buffer ( glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0) ) the textures get cleared to zero and everything that was drawn to the textures ends up back in the static buffers. Also, I have also tried binding two more empty textures to the framebuffer and everything gets moved to the new textures.

Here is [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIB3t.jpg) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yznk.jpg)

Any ideas?

Edited: removed code.

**TL;DR**: Problem was using EXTs (eg. glBindFramebufferEXT instead of glBindFramebuffer, etc).

Comment: Please post some [short, working code that demonstrates the problem](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: So the problem was fixed by removing all of the EXTs in function names and variables. Can I get some clarification on the difference between glBindFrameBuffer and glBindFrameBufferEXT and the like?

Comment: Use the `EXT` functions/enums if you found `EXT_framebuffer_object` in `GL_EXTENSIONS`.  If [`GL_VERSION` is >= 3.0](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) you can use the non-`EXT` versions.

Comment: @JakeSteak: please post your solution as an answer and accept the answer.